# Is there a way to disable intellisense in Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

The auto-complete/intellisense feature in MySQL Workbench is driving me up the wall, is there any way to disable it? I've had a dig through the settings & documentation but don't seem to be able to find any option for turning it off.

I'm working with the Linux build, v6.2.3.

Many thanks,
N00b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is called "Code Completion" in Workbench. Change it under Preferences -> [SQL Editor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-sql-editor.html) -> Query Editor. Here you can leave it enabled but disable "**Automatically Start Code Completion**", and then manually trigger it when needed. Or, disable it entirely. You can manually trigger it from the main menu under Edit -> Auto-complete, or use the shortcut key. That menu item shows the shortcut key for your platform.

Comment: Stirling. Thank you, I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: I can't believe here we are 8 years later and still Workbench's code completion is absolutely atrocious.